# What are the best regions to farm karthite?

Tags: rift

I'm trying to farm as much karthite as I can in Rift due to how expensive it is to purchase from other players. I've looked online to see where I can find a large amount of this material in game, however all I've found is articles stating that karthite can be found anywhere in the Storm Legion content.

Are there any specific regions that have a larger abundance of karthite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karthite has the highest chance to spawn in 54-57 areas such as Mordan and Ardent Domain.